# Python select.epoll().poll(), only polls eventmask 25

Tags: python, epoll

I've created a server with a RequestHandler that inherits from the `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler`  that polls socketEvents and Qevents using epoll.

For the first few times I connect the client to the server everything works as expected, until at some point (seems random) `epoll.poll()` only polls events `[(37,25)]`, and the %CPU becomes 99%.!  However the client doesn't raise any socket error.

My `handle()` method is as follows (part of the `RequestHandler`)

```
  def handle(self):
    """"
    This method will process the incoming request while exit is not set
    """
    try:
        while not self.exit.is_set():

            events = self.epoll.poll(1)
            print events
            if self.socketEvent in events:
                self.handle_request()

            if self.QEvent in events:
                self.send_response()

    finally:
        self.finish()
        return
```

I put the print statement there just to see what I was getting and when everything is working I get `[(37,1)]` (socketEvent) and `[(41,1)]`(QEvent). What is going on?

Comment: Are you handling closed connections? They return ready to read until they are closed and removed. (note: this is true for select and poll, I do not know epoll specifically)

Comment: I think the finish() method in the `BaseRequestHandler` handles the closed connections. I could be wrong so I'll need to check that.

Comment: Thanks @Max for pointing me in the right direction. The `finish()` method in the `BaseRequestHandler` doesn't do anything. Although this problem persist when the client closes the connection unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, then I found out that the `finish()` method in the `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler` does nothing to handle closed connections. What I did was following (this also takes care of when the client closes the connection unexpectedly):

```
def handle(self):
""""
This method will process the incoming request while exit is not set
"""
try:
    while not self.exit.is_set():

        events = self.epoll.poll(1)
        print events
        if self.socketEvent in events:
            self.handle_request()

        if self.QEvent in events:
            self.send_response()

        if (self.socketEvent[0],25) in events:
            self.exit.set()

finally:
    self.request.close()
    return
```